# MySQL 1 millon row query speed

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

I'm having trouble getting a decent query time out of a large MySQL table, currently its taking over 20 seconds.  The problem lies in the GROUP BY as MySQL needs to run a filesort but I don't see how I can get around this

**QUERY**:

```
SELECT play_date, COUNT(DISTINCT(email)) AS count 
FROM log 
WHERE type = 'play'
AND play_date BETWEEN '2009-02-23' 
AND '2009-02-24'
GROUP BY play_date 
ORDER BY play_date desc
```

**EXPLAIN**:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          log     ALL     type,type_2     NULL    NULL    NULL    530892  Using where; Using filesort
```

**TABLE STRUCTURE**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('played','reg','friend') NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `play_date` date NOT NULL,
  `email_refer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `remote_addr` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `email_refer` (`email_refer`),
  KEY `type_2` (`type`,`timestamp`,`play_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=707859 ;
```

If anyone knows how I could improve the speed I would be very greatful

Tom

***EDIT***

I've added the new index with just play_date and type but MySQL refuses to use it

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          log     ALL     play_date   NULL    NULL    NULL    801647  Using where; Using filesort
```

This index was created using ALTER TABLE `log` ADD INDEX (`type`, `play_date`);

Comment: Please post how eactly did you create the index on `(type, play_date)`

Comment: ALTER TABLE `log` ADD INDEX (`type`, `play_date`);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create index on fields `type` AND `play_date`.

Like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `log` ADD INDEX (`type`, `play_date`);
```

Or, alternately, you can rearrange your last key like this:

```
KEY `type_2` (`type`,`play_date`,`timestamp`)
```

so MySQL can use its left part as a key.

Comment: I've tried adding that key but MySQL refuses to use it, it states it as a possible index but then runs the query without using any indexes

id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE  log  ALL  play_date  NULL  NULL  NULL  801647  Using where; Using filesort

Answer (score 2):

You should add an index on the fields that you base your search on.

In your case it play_date and type

Answer (score 1):

You're not taking advantage of the key named `type_2`. It is a composite key for `type`, `timestamp` and `play_date`, but you're filtering by `type` and `play_date`, ignoring `timestamp`. Because of this, the engine can't make use of that key.

You should create an index on the fields `type` and `play_date`, or remove `timestamp` from the key `type_2`.

Or you could try to incorporate `timestamp` into your current query as a filter. But judging from your current query I don't think that is logical.

Answer (score 0):

Does there need to be an index on play_date, or move the position in the composite index to second place?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest options would be this

```
ALTER TABLE `log` ADD INDEX (`type`, `play_date`, 'email');
```

It would turn this index into a "covering index", which would mean that the query would only access the index stored in memory and not even goto the hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

The DESC parameter is causing MySQL not to use the index for the ORDER BY. You can leave it ASC and iterate the resultset in reverse on the client side (?).